# Drawing a rectangle using GraphicsPath in C# doesn't complete the drawing (GDI+)

Tags: c#-4.0, c#-3.0, gdi+, gdi

I have to draw a rectangle using lines whose co-ordinates and measures are already provided.

In the below code, if I call CloseFigure function. C# assumes the drawing is incomplete and hence it draws an another line diagonally to close the rectangle.

If I use a AddRectangle function, the drawing is complete. No issues with that.

How can I complete a drawing, properly using lines?

```
   private void OnPaint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Pen redPen = new Pen(Color.Red, 2);
        // Create a graphics path
        GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();
        // Add two lines, a rectangle and an ellipse
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        path.StartFigure();

        path.AddLine(20, 20, 20, 400); // left
        path.AddLine(20, 20, 400, 20); //top
        path.AddLine(400, 20, 400, 400); // right
        path.AddLine(20, 400, 400, 400); // bottom

        path.CloseFigure(); 
        //This will close the drawing, by drawing a line between starting and ending point
    }
```

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

You're drawing some of your lines "backwards" - for a connected shape, you always want the *end* coordinates of one line to be the *start* coordinates of the next line. So:

```
    path.AddLine(20, 400, 20, 20); // left
    path.AddLine(20, 20, 400, 20); //top
    path.AddLine(400, 20, 400, 400); // right
    path.AddLine(400, 400, 20, 400); // bottom
```

Comment: Hi Damien, Thank you. The real problem is I need to fill the rectangle using the below functions.   Region reg = new Region(path);
g.FillRegion(Brushes.Green, reg);  FillRegion function before filling a drawing, It calls the closefigure functionality internally, which in turn draws a line diagonally to complete the drawing.